# Может ли в python поток выполнения выполнить команду после `await` до завершения ожидания?

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

Предположим, у меня есть следующий код:

```
from my_module import MyTask
import asyncio

async def main():
    async def controll(fsuspend):
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        resume = await fsuspend()
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        await resume()
    
    run, suspend, cancel = MyTask()
    await run
    print('Test')
    await control(suspend)

asyncio.run(main())
```

1. Код функции `control` не будет запущен, пока не завершится ожидание функции `run`?
2. Как в асинхронном контексте мне проверить, что функция `suspend` работает?
3. Нужно использовать потоки, чтобы запустить `run` и `control` одновременно?
4. Функция `print` в данном случае выведет сообщение в консоль?
5. Функция `print` выведет сообщение **до** конца ожидания run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Каждый `await` блокирует выполнение в текущей асинхронной функции, пока ожидаемый объект не будет завершен (но позволяет в это время выполняться другим асинхронным объектам).

Чтобы ждать несколько объектов параллельно, не нужны потоки, достаточно ожидать их одновременно, обернув в [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) (либо использовать [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather), если нужно собрать результаты в список).

В вашем случае будет что-то типа

```
run, suspend, cancel = MyTask()
await asyncio.wait(run, control(suspend))
```

Исходя из этого:

1. Да
2. Как минимум, нужно запустить функцию с `await`. Простой "вызов" асинхронной функции со скобками, но без `await` (и без передачи ее например в какие-то другие функции, которые ожидание выполнят) фактически не запустит функцию на выполнение.
3. Используйте `asyncio.wait`, как я писал выше.
4. Да, если `run` когда-либо завершится
5. Нет, будет выполняться ожидание `run`